# Notifying New users Questions response via email

Tags: feature-request, support, user-interface, new-users, email-notification

Though SE have policy not to send e-mails but Our community 'Ask Patents' drive lot of traffic from user outside SE ecosystem (Thanks to Google Patents 'Discuss' button) and being new they don't know how the SE system works. I feel our community drive question from user as 'unregistered user' (cookie based) and later user fails to recall where he posted it or no track of it. I believe for such user e-mail notification on answer and comments will be more useful and site health is improved.

To make it more precise when a registered user asks a question one check-box is present to ask **'Send me new responses to my posts via email'** [Question in Ask Patents Meta](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/258/11895). However this option is not available for first time askers posting as guest (i.e. new user not logged in). Ideally it should be checked by default (hard to find any way). Is anything missing here for first time user?

I believe for first time user **only** email update can be by default. by this way guest user is updated. our 'Ask Patent' is quite about late answer type quality answer comes from 2 days or after few weeks and user forgets the same in meantime.

I also placed a bounty over following question
[What do we do to keep new users coming back to the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240516/282585) ; and it came to my notice that that is kind of discussion and I need to make a feature request.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they should be able to receive notifications in their email if their are not a registered user. Being a registered user gives you privileges, and I see receiving email notifications as one of them.

One option is that the check box could be shown and when checked it shows a page you need to register first. In that way people know what they can expect.

Also I had like to see *why* a user should register in the Ask Question page when the user isn't registered yet. This could encourage users to register.